# What is the order of the alternating group $A_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

When I write out all the elements of $S_4$, I count only 11 transpositions. But in my text, the order of $A_4$ is $12$. What am I missing?

$A_4=\{(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23),(123),(124),(132),(134),(142),(143),(234),(243)$

$|A_4|=11$

Comment: What do transpositions have to do with the  order of $\;A_4\;$ here? And BTW: none of the elements of $\;A_4\;$ is a transposition...

Comment: But the identity is not an even transposition..

Comment: @Timbuc, transpositions are even cycles w.r.t symmetric groups

Comment: It's still an element of $A_4$

Comment: I think you may be confusing transpositions = permutations of the form $\;(i_1\;i_2)\;$ with permutations in general.

Comment: No @atherton, that is not what transpositions are.

Comment: @Eoin, ah yes, since $A_4$ is group, must have a identity. Clicked

Comment: Transpositions are **always** odd permutations: none of them can belong to $\;A_n\;$ .

Comment: The identity is an even permutation.  If it weren't,  $A_4$ wouldn't be a group since it wouldn't have an identity element.

Comment: @Timbuc isn't the definition of transpositions = permutations of the form $\;(i_1\;i_2)\;$?

Comment: Exactly, @atherton , and those are **odd** permutations, of course:they interchangte two elements and keep all the rest fixed.

Comment: How many times do you have to swap elements in order to "implement" the identity permutation?  Is this number of times even?

Comment: @David The answer to your question is $0$, which is an even number. The identity element of a group is an empty product.

Comment: @DerekHolt Exactly my point.  Contrary to some comments above, the identity **is** an even permutation.  And it's not, as some comments appeared to suggest, that "it's not even but we need it anyway since the group must have an identity".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the identity element. It can be written as an "even" permutation:
$$(12)(12)$$

Comment: It's also an empty product of zero transpositions, but that is strangely more difficult to write!

Comment: $$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Comment: Quite easy to write, see my previous comment ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The order of $A_n$ is always half the order of $S_n$, consider the bijective map from the even permutations to the odd permutations where $\varphi(\pi)=(12)\pi $. This is a bijection since the inverse is the map from the odd permutations to the even permutations $\varphi^{-1}(\pi)=(12)\pi$.

Comment: This answer is great because it does not use the "formula" for the quotient set/subgroup! +1

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sign homomorphism $\varphi:S_n\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$, which maps even permutations to 1 and odd permutations to -1. Notice that $\ker \varphi = A_n$, and since $\varphi$ is surjective, 
\begin{align*}
\lvert \ker \varphi \lvert = \frac{\lvert S_n \lvert}{\lvert \{\pm 1\}\lvert}=\frac{n!}{2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

As $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, there should be identity and identity is a even permutation.

identity $e=(13)(13)$